# How to implement an EditText containing TextViews

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, textview

I have trouble implementing the EditText below.

[image: Example]

This would be the behavior of the EditText.

1. After the user enters a text and presses done, a textview with a grey background would be created in front of the edittext. eg. Apple, Banana. The cursor would then reposition in front of the created TextView.
2. The user would be able to place the cursor between Apple and Banana and upon backpress, the textview before the cursor would be removed.
3. In case the width of the elements inside the EditText exceeds the screen, you would be able to scroll horizontally inside.

I have tried creating a parent LinearLayout with an underline background which has a RecyclerView and EditText inside. Upon enter, I would add an element in the RecyclerView and increase it's width while the EditText inside will be positioned in front of the RecyclerView which would work in some scenarios but is a very sloppy workaround and won't work in scenario 2.

I haven't found anything that has encountered this same scenario which explains how but I think have seen this same behavior in various apps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Regards,

Comment: Seems like you reinvent chips control https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f

Comment: use this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3102